# Почему при успешном ajax запросе срабатывает функция error?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

У меня есть `ajax` запрос, который пересылает логин и пароль сервлету. Сервлет их получает, но при этом в `ajax` запускается функция `error`, которая, если верить документации, срабатывает в случае неуспешного запроса. Почему так происходит?

Код запроса

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login-button").click(function(){
            var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
            var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
            var dataString = "log_in " + userLogin + " " + userPassword;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8181/library/login",
                data: { login: userLogin, password: userPassword },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Welcome!");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                    alert("Wrong login or password");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: А что сервлет возвращает ?

Comment: смотрите значение _textStatus,errorThrown_ ну и вообще ошибки в консли

Comment: В textStatus значение error, в errorThrown пусто

Comment: Сервлет возвращает текстовую строку